# Python Handle SSL Request Exception in API call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a script that will be run through an RMM across all the devices at a site. This is my first script that I have tried adding any kind of error handling so I am still new to this concept. This script is targeting the firewall's API and they only allow one connection at a time. About half the devices I get the expected output and the others I get an SSL error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/sonicos/auth (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1006)')))
[23764] Failed to execute script 'logintest' due to unhandled exception!
```

I am trying to catch this error and just exit if this error occurs in the following way:

```
try:
      something()
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as sslexception:
      print(f"Too many connections at one time. {sslexception}")
      sys.exit(0) # 0 is the exit code for all is good in our RMM
```

This error has still been happening. I have tried adding the try\except to the main() as well and haven't been able to get this error to pass. Any help is appreciated.

Python Version 3.11.5

Comment: so `try/catch` blocks are useful when you want to for example undertake alternative actions in case of failures. It will not solve the root cause of problem. Root cause of problem seems to be your self signed certificate. Pass  `requests.get(your_url, verify=False)` to disable SSL verification.

Comment: @BijayRegmi Ok that makes sense. So try/catch is the wrong thing to be doing here. I may be wrong but I don't think this error has anything to do with a self signed certificate. `Max retries exceeded with url: /api/sonicos/auth` This part of the error is because another node I ran this on was trying to connect to the firewall at the same time and the firewalls API only allows one connection at a time. Where would I put the `requests.get(your_url, verify=False)` in the script to be able to test this?

Comment: `'[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1006)'` tells you that the server SSL configs might be outdated or not of security level expected. With parameter `verify=False` you ask `requests` package not to verify SSL while making connections. So use this whenever you are connecting with your host `192.168.0.1`. Other option would be to deploy proper SSL settings on serverside with proper certificate.